# Why gap appears when switch from img to next/image?

Tags: css, image, next.js

I have here my site: https://tikex-dev.com

This part I talk about:

[image]

Down at the bottom of the image a 'gap' appers.

All I did replaced standard html `img` with Next.js `Image`, like this:

```js
<Image
        src="https://ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/b29418ef-156d-43d7-872e-5d180cd1feb0"
        alt=""
        width={338}
        height={226}
/>
```

Added `width` and `height` as it is required.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: you added a `background: #000` in `.img-box:before` CSS selector. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dMwO.jpg (maybe is there the bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `layout` prop to your `next/image`

```
<Image
        src="https://ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/b29418ef-156d-43d7-872e-5d180cd1feb0"
        alt=""
        width={338}
        height={226}
        layout="responsive"
/>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked :) Would you explain me why? :)